# Displaying the order of the columns of a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I created a table, and want to find the display the order of its columns. 
Should I use the following query to display the info ordered by `column_id`?

```
select * from sys.columns c
where c.object_id = object_id('Customer')
order by column_id


create table dbo.Customer
(
    CustomerId int primary key,
    CustomerName varchar(255),
    CustomerAddress varchar(255),
    EnrollmentDate date
)
```

Reading [Microsoft SQL Server documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), I am seeing the information below, so want to be sure:

```
Column name  Data type  Description
-----------  ---------  ---------------------------------------------- 
column_id:   int        ID of the column. Is unique within the object.
                        Column IDs might not be sequential.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`column_id` is a reasonable proxy for the column ordinal, since it is impossible to insert a column between two existing columns in SQL Server without dropping and recreating the table.

As the documentation states, `column_id` values may not be sequential if you drop a column from a table.

You can also make use of the [COLUMNPROPERTY()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/columnproperty-transact-sql) function to return the actual ordinal for each column.

Consider a quick example:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.t', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.t;
CREATE TABLE dbo.t
(
    c1 int
    , c2 int
    , c3 int
    , c4 int
);

ALTER TABLE dbo.t DROP COLUMN c1;
ALTER TABLE dbo.t ADD c5 int;
ALTER TABLE dbo.t ALTER COLUMN c2 char(3);

SELECT o.name
    , c.name
    , c.column_id
    , ordinal = COLUMNPROPERTY(c.object_id, c.name, 'ordinal')
FROM sys.columns c
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON c.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE o.name = N't'
```

The output looks like:

```
╔══════╦══════╦═══════════╦═════════╗
║ name ║ name ║ column_id ║ ordinal ║
╠══════╬══════╬═══════════╬═════════╣
║ t    ║ c2   ║         2 ║       1 ║
║ t    ║ c3   ║         3 ║       2 ║
║ t    ║ c4   ║         4 ║       3 ║
║ t    ║ c5   ║         5 ║       4 ║
╚══════╩══════╩═══════════╩═════════╝
```

Comment: The "ordinal" column property works, but Microsoft's documentation of `COLUMNPROPERTY` doesn't mention `'ordinal'` as one of the allowed values.

Answer (score 2):

Just to propose an additional answer that will tell you the actual column position instead of column_id

```
select column_name, ORDINAL_POSITION 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where table_name = 'your_table'
```