# How to display name and type of table columns in creation order?

Tags: postgresql, information-schema, postgresql-14, pg-catalog

I have created this `tbl_cities` using the code below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.tbl_Cities
  (City_ID SERIAL NOT NULL,
   City_Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   City_State_Region VARCHAR(100),
   ID_Country INT NOT NULL,

   CONSTRAINT PK_City_ID PRIMARY KEY (City_ID));
```

Now I want to query **the exact same order of this columns and their datatype,** in order to make sure, what are the column names and what is the real column order (without scrolling back to the `CREATE TABLE` statement). In context of the `INSERT` statements I'm about to write and execute.

To learn this info I execute:

```
SELECT column_name, data_type FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'tbl_cities';
```

But the output I get is in different order, than the columns exist in reality.

[image]

I've also tried to order the columns, but the only parameter I know is
`ORDER BY column_name`. In this very case it results in the correct order in which the columns exist in reality.

```
SELECT column_name, data_type FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'tbl_cities'
ORDER BY column_name;
```

My **question** is: What is the correct syntax to achieve the **real order in which the columns are in the table,** in case ordering them alphabetically would return different result/order.

I have found [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/233179/displaying-the-order-of-the-columns-of-a-table), but it concerns SQL Server and I need to do this on PostgreSQL v14.7.

**I'm open to different answers** using not only `information_schema.columns` but also any kind of this other thing:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables;
```

Comment: Perhaps [`ordinal_position`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-columns.html) is what you're after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Postgres, catalog tables are the true source of information. For this case in particular: [`pg_attribute`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-attribute.html). The column `attnum` represents the physical order (= logical order) of columns:

```
SELECT attname AS column_name
--   , atttypid::regtype AS data_type                       -- simple
     , format_type(atttypid, atttypmod) AS exact_data_type  -- exact
FROM   pg_attribute
WHERE  attrelid = 'public.tbl_cities'::regclass
AND    attnum > 0
AND    NOT attisdropped
ORDER  BY attnum;
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-attribute.html)

> `attnum` `int2`
>
> The number of the column. Ordinary columns are numbered from 1 up.
> System columns, such as `ctid`, have (arbitrary) negative numbers.

The information schema is a standardized view on the same. But some details like *exact* data type are much easier to extract from `pg_attribute`. And faster.

I use the ["system catalog information function" `format_type()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) to get the exact data type, which includes modifiers and also works for array types and domains. You'll want that. Think of `varchar(25)[]` ...

Producing the same from `information_schema.columns` is not as simple (or fast). [The manual about the column `information_schema.columns.data_type`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-columns.html):

> Data type of the column, if it is a built-in type, or `ARRAY` if it is
> some array (in that case, see the view `element_types`), else
> `USER-DEFINED` (in that case, the type is identified in `udt_name` and
> associated columns). If the column is based on a domain, this column
> refers to the type underlying the domain (and the domain is identified
> in `domain_name` and associated columns).

See:

- [List all columns for a specified table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22362/list-all-columns-for-a-specified-table/22420#22420)
- [Get column names and data types of a query, table or view](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75015/get-column-names-and-data-types-of-a-query-table-or-view/75124#75124)

Comment: Where can I read more about what is ```pg_catalogue``` and ```pg_attribute``` and differences between them??

Comment: @michalroesler Start with the links to the manual and more elaborate answers I provided. `pg_catalogue` is the schema where system tables like `pg_attribute`  live.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer to use the `information_schema` for a question like this:

```
SELECT ordinal_position, column_name, data_type
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'public'
  AND table_name = 'tbl_cities'
ORDER BY ordinal_position;
```